# Is there way to create empty .mo file template?

Tags: templates, gettext

Is there way of creating empty .mo file? Usually when starting new project I get stuck with this when there's no need for translations yet.

I tried this with no luck:

```
msgfmt /dev/null --output-file foo.mo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.

```
xgettext --force-po -f /dev/null -o foo.po
msgfmt foo.po --output-file foo.mo
```